# Update don´t get the value of local when doing an update using i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have tried to use i18n internationalization in my application.

It works very well when I do a Show (index), Create, and Edit. My problem is when I do an update.

When I press the update button I don´t get the :locale value back

**Normaly I get these values back.**

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
level: '5_3'
menu_item: '5'
menu_level: '5_3_1'
action: index
controller: communication_mails
locale: dk
```

The URL looks like:
localhost:3000/dk/communication_mails

When I press the Edit button I get these values back. (The “Button” is a link). Locale is still ok.

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
level: '5_3'
menu_item: '5'
menu_level: '5_3_2'
action: edit
controller: communication_mails
locale: dk
id: '2'
```

The URL now looks like:
localhost:3000/dk/communication_mails/2/edit

**My problem is** when I now press the “Update” button under the form field the redirection don´t get the value of locale back... It instead uses the ID.

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
level: '5_3'
menu_item: '5'
menu_level: '5_3_1'
action: index
controller: communication_mails
locale: '2'
```

The URL now looks like:
localhost:3000/2/communication_mails

My route looks something likes this:

```
 scope "/:locale" do
    resources :communication_mails
  end


  resources :communication_mails do
    collection do
      get 'communication_mails'
      post 'communication_mails'
      put 'communication_mails'
    end
  end

  root :to => redirect("/dk/tests/")
  match '/communication_mails/:id/edit(.:format)', :to => 'communication_mails#edit'
  match '/communication_mails/:id/', :to => 'communication_mails#index'
  match '/communication_mails', :to => 'communication_mails#index'
```

My Controller is made like this.

```
  def edit
    @communication_mail = CommunicationMail.find(params[:id])
    @show_calendars = Calendar.where(:calendar_priority => '1')
    @show_email_text = CommunicationMail.find_by_sql("SELECT calendars.id,
    calendar_name, communication_mail_headline, communication_mail_text
    FROM calendars LEFT OUTER JOIN communication_mails 
    ON communication_mails.communication_mail_calendar_id = calendars.id
    WHERE communication_mails.communication_mail_priority = '1'")
  end

  def update
    @communication_mail = CommunicationMail.update(params[:id], params[:communication_mail])
    @show_calendars = Calendar.where(:calendar_priority => '1')
    @show_email_text = CommunicationMail.find_by_sql("SELECT calendars.id,
    calendar_name, communication_mail_headline, communication_mail_text
    FROM calendars LEFT OUTER JOIN communication_mails 
    ON communication_mails.communication_mail_calendar_id = calendars.id
    WHERE communication_mails.communication_mail_priority = '1'")
    if @communication_mail
      redirect_to communication_mails_path(:menu_item => '5', :level => '5_3', :menu_level => '5_3_1'), 
        :notice => 'Opdateringen af E-mail tekst lykkedes'
    else
      redirect_to communication_mails_path(:menu_item => '5', :level => '5_3', :menu_level => '5_3_1'), 
        :notice => 'Opdateringen af E-mail tekst lykkedes IKKE'
    end    
  end
```

I have solved many questions by looking through these pages. But I can´t find an answer to this one. 
I hope some one can help me out. Thanks in in advance.

UPDATE

My routes looks like this:

```
GET    /:locale/communication_mails/communication_mails(.:format)     communication_mails#communication_mails
POST   /:locale/communication_mails/communication_mails(.:format)      communication_mails#communication_mails
PUT    /:locale/communication_mails/communication_mails(.:format)  communication_mails#communication_mails
GET    /:locale/communication_mails(.:format)               communication_mails#index
POST   /:locale/communication_mails(.:format)               communication_mails#create
GET    /:locale/communication_mails/new(.:format)           communication_mails#new
GET    /:locale/communication_mails/:id/edit(.:format)      communication_mails#edit
GET    /:locale/communication_mails/:id(.:format)           communication_mails#show
PUT    /:locale/communication_mails/:id(.:format)           communication_mails#update
DELETE /:locale/communication_mails/:id(.:format)           communication_mails#destroy
```

The form I use to send and update the data

```
<%= form_for(@communication_mail) do |f| %>
  <table class="toggle_header2">
    <tr>
      <td class="nobr width50px font_size13 font_weight_bold color03 border_left">
        <%= t('forms.calendar') %> 
      </td>
      <td class="color03 border_right">      
        <%= collection_select(:communication_mail, 
          :communication_mail_calendar_id, 
          @show_calendars, 
          :id, 
          :calendar_name, 
          {:include_blank => true }, 
          {:prompt => true})
       %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nobr width50px font_size13 font_weight_bold color03 border_left">
        <%= t('forms.headline') %>
      </td>
      <td class="color03 border_right">
        <%= f.text_field :communication_mail_headline, :class => 'width350px' %>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="nobr align_top font_size13 font_weight_bold color03 border_left">
        <%= t('forms.text') %>
      </td>
      <td class="color03 border_right">
        <%= f.text_area :communication_mail_text, :class => 'width350px' %>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="color03 border_left">
        <%= f.hidden_field :communication_mail_priority, :value => '1' %>
      </td>
      <td class="color03 border_right">
      <% if action_name == 'edit' || action_name == 'update'  %>
        <%= f.submit t('buttons.update') %> 
      <% else %>
        <%= f.submit t('buttons.insert') %> 
      <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pick your `:locale` value from params, you have incorrect approach in your routing.

***Update: be sure you are passing :locale value to your routing helpers on update action.***

This code will generate routes with scope only for `index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy` actions.

```
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :communication_mails
end
```

This code will add additional routes to :communication_mails, but without scope.

```
  resources :communication_mails do
    collection do
      get 'communication_mails'
      post 'communication_mails'
      put 'communication_mails'
    end
  end
```

Solution is to combine. You have to define :scope for all of your `:communication_mails` actions.

```
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :communication_mails do
    collection do
      get 'communication_mails'
      post 'communication_mails'
      put 'communication_mails'
    end
  end
end
```

Please read documentation about routing (it is basics): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Hi thesis
Thank you for your answer... I tried to Scope all actions but it does not work. It is a bid confusing all other actions work except Update.

Comment: Hm, strange. Please post here your update form and results of `rake routes` command.